# jQuery mobile fixed navbar toolbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm new to web development, I'm trying to create a static footer navbar that won't disappear with scrolling. I tried many examples here on stackoverflow but none of them work for me. The footer just disappears after i start scrolling.
here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQueryMoblie</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css"/>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">  

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $.("[data-role=footer]").setTouchToggleEnabled(false);

        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText = "indietro";
        $('a.item').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.mobile.changePage({
                url: "result.php",
                type: "get",
                data: "id="+id
            },"slide");
            return false;
            });
        });
</script>

</head>
<body>  

<div data-role="page" id="lista">
    <div data-role="header">

        <h1>Lista </h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d">

        <?php            
        $type= "";

$type = $_REQUEST['type'];

            include_once 'resultList.class.php';
    $author->showList($type);

        ?>
        </ul>
   </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

<div data-role="navbar"data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are testing this on a what platform? And why don't you try it with jQuery Mobile version 1.3.1?

Comment: thanks a lot! including the latest jQuery version solved my problem. I'm testing on firefox desktop browser and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, should work

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Single page</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <p>This is a single page boilerplate template that you can copy to build your first jQuery Mobile page. Each link or form from here will pull a new page in via Ajax to support the animated page transitions.</p>      
    <p>Just view the source and copy the code to get started. All the CSS and JS is linked to the jQuery CDN versions so this is super easy to set up. Remember to include a meta viewport tag in the head to set the zoom level.</p>
    <p>This template is standard HTML document with a single "page" container inside, unlike a <a href="multipage-template.html" data-ajax="false">multi-page template</a> that has multiple pages within it. We strongly recommend building your site or app as a series of separate pages like this because it's cleaner, more lightweight and works better without JavaScript.</p>

    <p>This is a single page boilerplate template that you can copy to build your first jQuery Mobile page. Each link or form from here will pull a new page in via Ajax to support the animated page transitions.</p>      
    <p>Just view the source and copy the code to get started. All the CSS and JS is linked to the jQuery CDN versions so this is super easy to set up. Remember to include a meta viewport tag in the head to set the zoom level.</p>
    <p>This template is standard HTML document with a single "page" container inside, unlike a <a href="multipage-template.html" data-ajax="false">multi-page template</a> that has multiple pages within it. We strongly recommend building your site or app as a series of separate pages like this because it's cleaner, more lightweight and works better without JavaScript.</p>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h4>Footer content</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

http://readystate.in/codetest/jquerymobile.html